# How to update the column of one table when another one is edited

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have one table with columns consisting of an id, name, description, and a count. Each row in this table has a name that corresponds to another table.

For instance, one of my rows is has the name "carcinoma". There exists another table that is named "carcinoma".

I would like the count of column of the first table to update every time a row is added the "carcinoma" column. For instance, if table "carcinoma" has 4 rows, I want the count column in the first table to have a value of 4 for the carcinoma row. Is there a way where the count column auto updates when I insert or delete a row from the second table?

## First Table

ID               Name                  Count
1                Carcinoma             0

## Second Table Named Carcinoma

ID               Name
1                Squamous Cell
2                Adeno
3                Basal cell
4                Ductal cell

Comment: share sample table and its data and what would be table after update

Comment: Hmm, what you want do seems at least dubious. But lets assume your approaching a very special case where this is reasonable. Nevertheless you might think about using a view instead of a table where you simply get the `count(*)` from the other table(s).

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I tried my best to show the tables, basically the count column in the first table should be 4. Then, if I delete a row in the second column, the count in the first column should update to 3

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a trigger on each of the secondary tables.  For instance:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER carcinoma_increment AFTER INSERT ON carcinoma
       FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE firsttable
        SET count = count + 1
        WHERE name = 'Carcinoma';
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

You may also want `DELETE` triggers on the tables as well.